# App_Model does not exist in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am new to django and have a bit of a problem. I was creating a simple view, template and models for small project. I was getting error that Vote_Type does not exist, when I was asking for Type model in 'Vote' app. I don't get why is it looking for Vote_Type instead of Type in database.

So I went to look for a problem and now that I tried to create a object of model Type in database from python console I got the same error.

This is my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Voted_Object(models.Model):
    Voted_Object_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Voted_Object_image = models.ImageField
    Voted_Object_rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Voted_Object_Id = models.IntegerField

class Type(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    Type_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Type_Id = models.IntegerField
```

and this is the error I get when I try to do Type.objects.all() in python console.

> relation "Vote_type" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...te_type"."pub_date", "Vote_type"."Type_name" FROM "Vote_type..

What is wrong with my code? why is django looking for Vote_Type instead of Type

Comment: Have you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: I am sure I have, but let me check do it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Django creates tables with the naming scheme "`{app_name}_{class_name}`" - so it is expecting to find a table called "Vote_type" in the database that corresponds to the `Type` model in the `Vote` app. Did you create and run migrations to add the table, or do this manually?

Unrelated, but can I suggest you structure you app like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Vote(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField()
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class VoteType(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

- You don't need `id` fields - they're added automatically
- Prefixing field names just makes things verbose. `vote.name` is much easier to write/understand than `vote.Voted_Object_name`. Same for the `_Object` suffix.
- `type` is a keyword, so maybe use `VoteType` instead.

Comment: Thx for suggestions! I am sure I have run migrations, but let me do it again just to make sure.

Comment: yep, it worked. Sorry for silly question I was sure I made migrations. I think that I forgot to do migrate.